# Android - draw line vertically

Tags: android

I have a custom view where I override the onDraw method and drawn a circle. Now I  want to draw a line from the center of the circle to the top of the circle.

Here is my code..

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), backgroundPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, outerRadius, outerCirclePaint);

    double angleRadians = Math.toRadians(0);

    double x = (outerRadius * Math.cos(angleRadians)) + centerX;
    double y = (outerRadius * Math.sin(angleRadians)) + centerY;

    canvas.drawLine((float)x, (float)y, centerX, centerY, innerCirclePaint);
}
```

centerX and centerY are the center of the circle
outerRadius is the radius for the circle

When i run this the line is drawn from the center to the right at 90 degrees instead of the top of the circle 0 degrees, even though I have told it the angle is 0

This is confusing me and can't seem what I am doing wrong.
If anyone has any ideas on this I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematics, 0 degrees (also 0 radians) for the unit circle start at the right of the circle.

[Unit circle](http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/43200/43217/unit-circle9_43217_md.gif)

Add 90 degrees or pi/2 radians to start at the top.